# How to convert file back to directory

Tags: macos, filesystems

My coworker, using OSX, uploaded a .xcappdata file to Asana. This "file" is actually a directory that OSX likes to treat like a file (so many ways I hate Apple). For some reason, Safari allowed this "file" to be uploaded. Now, when I download it, it is actually a file (no longer a directory) and its size is 9.8MB, which is correct, so the data is there (right?). How do I recover this directory? My coworker no longer has the original.

Comment: On which OS did you download it? If on OS X, did you try right-clicking the xcappdata file and selecting *Show Package Contents*? On Windows perhaps you can append the .ZIP extension and see if it opens.

Comment: I'm on OS X, but the file was indeed a .zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appended .zip to the file name, and it opened correctly when I double clicked it.